# Deploying an R plumber API with the plumberDeploy package on Digital Ocean

Tags: r, digital-ocean, plumber

I have been trying to deploy my plumber api in r using the plumberDeploy package but it keeps returning an error that is related with the 'path' parameter. I have activated my digital ocean account and I have provisioned the droplet. When I run my code:

```r
plumberDeploy::do_deploy_api(id, "regr", "./Creating the regression model API using plumber/", 8082, docs = TRUE)
```

It returns the following error:

> *mv: target '/var/plumber/regr' is not a directory
> Error: ssh failed
> mv /tmp/SEYDWIQRFF/Creating the regression model API using plumber/ /var/plumber/regr*. Please how can I solve this?